# MongoDB size limit sulotions

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using windows server with node js express and MongoDB.

I have a JSON object with a size of 50MB I need to save into the DB after reading and exploring the web I read about grid fs which sound like a great option for me. but I only see the usage of grid fs is to store files such as mp3 or images... my object is JSON file which I want to save in my collection and not in grid fs collection.
Hoping to find a better solution before I switch the DB to SQL

Comment: You could dump the JSON to a file and save that file. GridFS doesn't care about the file type.

Comment: Or split that JSON input several JSON objects that are stored separately. Its a really bad idea to store 50MB blobs as your raw documents.